# websockets and java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, websocket

Does anyone know if there is a good (where good is stable enough to use, and open-source) webSocket servlet implementation? The one that possibly complies with draft spec 76 (the latest one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) [supports](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature#Headline_Features) [websockets](http://blogs.webtide.com/gregw/entry/jetty_websocket_server), [Resin](http://www.caucho.com/) [supports websockets](http://www.caucho.com/resin-4.0/examples/websocket-java/index.xtp) and [Glassfish 3.0.1](http://glassfish.dev.java.net) [supports](http://www.antwerkz.com/glassfish-web-sockets-sample/) it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hoped somebody would point me to some other implementation. I knew about this one wanted to see if there is any alternative.

Comment: Resin and Glassfish are another ones, but they're a heavyweight appserver while Jetty is light, small and embeddable and ideal for developments.

Answer (score 0):

Kaazing offers a websocket gateway with more advance java features on top like jms!!